# MongoDB: variables and runCommand

Tags: mongodb

I find myself running up against my first "I just can't figure out how to do this using mongo" problem.

I have the following "schema":

- a collection of **elements**. What is on them is unimportant
- a collection of **connections**. Each entry is defined as follows:

  - fst_id: id of first element
  - snd_id: id of second element
  - forwards: a bool indicating whether we navigate from first to second or vice versa

The collections aren't that small; **elements** will end up containing 100 million documents or so; **connections** will end up containing about 200 million documents or so.

The query that I want to make is "given a set of element ids S, find me the set of connections for which both ends are in S". A typical size for S would be several hundred thousand.

Now, if I were doing this in the mongo shell, it would be relatively simple (provided I didn't mind pasting in an array of a million values; I'm sure there is a reasonable way to define this, but you'll see why in a moment that this isn't the point):

```
var s = ["id1","id2",..."id99999"]
db.connections.find(
  {
    $and: [
      {fst_id: {$in: s}},
      {snd_id: {$in: s}}
    ]
  }
)
```

This would be great, except I am connecting through the legacy c++ driver so what I have access to is a query function on the db connection class that takes a BSON object. As such I seem to be limited to generating the following code (ignoring the fine details of building the command):

```
db.connections.find(
  {
    $and: [
      {fst_id: {$in: ["id1","id2",..."id99999"]}},
      {snd_id: {$in: ["id1","id2",..."id99999"]}}
    ]
  }
)
```

That big, horrible array gets duplicated. I can take it as a necessary evil that I have to define it once. Defining it twice seems blasphemous.

I tried defining a function through db.system.js but I can't run it through runCommand without requiring the user to have admin privileges and, in any case, the MongoDB community responds with an emphatic NO whenever someone asks about it.

I suppose I could keep the array of sequences in a collection but then I have the whole extra question of how to query one collection given another collection.

My options, as I see them:

1. Live with the duplication of the large array for the query
2. Modify the schema so that each element contains ids for the connections it is involved with (this increases the db size and comes with its own complications)
3. "Somehow" call mongo without having to shell out to the command line
4. Go the runCommand(eval... route with admin privileges
5. Anything else that you folks can suggest

Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: Side note: the top level `$and` is implicit; no need to add it

Comment: Of course you can use variables when constructing a BSON object. How about editing your question down to be less "back story" and "musing" on the subject and more "code" and "to the point" explaination. You can basically cut the whole thing down to *"How do I use an array variable within a BSON object?"*. Simple and too the point. People are ignoring your question because it takes too long to get to the point in reading and you don't have the correct tags either. Be concise.

Comment: I don't think it does boil down to that. I know how to construct an array variable when building BSON objects. The problem that I have is that, unlike in the shell where you can define a var and then use it in multiple places, I can't/don't know how to build a query that uses the variable twice without duplicating its contents.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I think the issue is that the OP does not want to *send* the same extremely long array twice in the query. But I don't think you can get around that in this case.